# how to get property from other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to access var w value from other function. Is it possible.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var first = {
myFirst: function(){
var w= 90;
var q=12;
}}


var second= {
mySecond: function(){
first.myFirst.w     
}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

In that way you cannot access `w` because it's defined in the local scope of `myFirst`. You can do something like:

```
var first = {
  myFirst: function(){
    first.myFirst.w = 90;
    var q=12;
  }
};

var second= {
  mySecond: function(){
    alert(first.myFirst.w);
  }
};

first.myFirst();
second.mySecond(); //alerts 90
```

In that way `w` will be added as property of the function `myFirst`, if you want to add it as property of `first`, use:

```
var first = {
  myFirst: function(){
    this.w = 90;
    var q=12;
  }
};

var second= {
  mySecond: function(){
    alert(first.w);
  }
};

first.myFirst();
second.mySecond(); //alerts 90
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible, because the scope of w is within the function. Once the function has been called w no longer exists.

Also, technically you would need to call first.myFirst().w;

To get that to work you could do this instead:

```
var first = {
  myFirst: function(){
    var w= 90;
    var q=12;
    return { w : w };
  }
}

first.myFirst().w // now works.
```

Comment: yeah, just fixed it, sorry. got confused (easy to do in javascript unfortunately).